# Android приложение не обновляется

Tags: android

Выкинул новое обновление приложения на Google Play в тестовом режиме. При попытке обновить, приложение скачивается, но когда начинает переустанавливаться почти сразу закрывается установка (и соответственно не обновляется). Но если сначала удалить приложение с телефона и заново с Google Play установить, то все устанавливается. Подскажите в какую сторону копать в чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Comment: Как минимум читайте логи

Comment: А где эти логи почитать? Если это происходит непосредственно при установке с Google Play? Установка просто прерывается

Comment: Как обычно в logcat

Comment: Предыдущая версия тоже из маркета установлена?

Comment: Таки да - уточните, не ставите ли поверх версии, которую из студии устанавливали - весьма вероятно, что вы получаете конфликт подписей приложения. Если не получается обновить версию из маркета новой из маркета же - попробуйте таки логи посмотреть какие-то. По идее, если все фильтры в LogCat отключить - должно что-то видно быть. Чтобы не мучиться с маркетом - скачайте из него же, из консоли разработчика файлы старой и новой версии и вручную их одну на другую накатывайте и смотрите что в логах будет.